# Mongo Conditional Condition in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to be able to have an API that can filter based on a date. So you pass in something like the following:

```
    dob: {
        date: new Date("5/22/1955"),
        filter: 'lt'
    }
```

This should return all records with DOB less than the date, but if "gte" was passed in the filter, than it should return all records with DOB greater than or equal to the date.

Obviously, the Mongo queries would be

```
dobQuery = {dob: {gte: data.dob.date}};
dobQuery = {dob: {lt: data.dob.date}};
```

But how could I make this conditional? I want to write something like this, but of course this doesn't work:

```
dobQuery = {dob : {"$" + data.dob.filter: data.dob.date}};
```

How can I write that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build `dobQuery` up programmatically using bracket notation:

```
dobQuery = {dob: {}};
dobQuery.dob['$' + data.dob.filter] = data.dob.date;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Clean and concise thanks.